# (Ffmpeg) How to play live audio in the browser from received UDP packets using Ffmpeg?

Tags: node.js, c#-4.0, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I have .NET Core console application which acts as UDP Server and UDP Client

- UDP client by receiving audio packet.
- UDP server, by sending each received packet.

Here's a sample code of the console app:

```
static UdpClient udpListener = new UdpClient();
    static IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.230"), 6980);
    static IAudioSender audioSender = new UdpAudioSender(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.230"), 65535));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        udpListener.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        udpListener.Client.Bind(endPoint);

        try
        {
            udpListener.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to dispose the running service");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private async static void recv(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        byte[] received = udpListener.EndReceive(res, ref endPoint);
        OnAudioCaptured(received);
        udpListener.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
    }
```

On the other side, I have a node js API application, which supposes to execute an FFmpeg command as a child process and to do the following

- receive the audio packet as an input from the console app UDP server.
- convert the received bytes into WebM
- pipe out the result into the response.

Finally, in the client-side, I should have an audio element with source value equals to the http://localhost:3000

For now, I can only execute this FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f  s16le  -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i 'udp://192.168.1.230:65535' output.wav
```

Which do the following

- Receive UDP packet as an input
- Convert the received bytes into the output.wav audio file.

How would I execute a child process in the node js server which receives the UDP packets and pipe out the result into the response as Webm?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is use something like FFmpeg to wrap those PCM samples in WebM via a child process.  `ffmpeg -i - -acodec copy -f webm -`  (Or, drop the `-acodec copy` if you don't need lossless audio.)  Then, output that stream to your client.  Client-side, you just need to do something like `<audio src="https://your-node-server.example.com/stream" controls preload="none"></audio>`.  Much simpler.  No need for Socket.IO, the browser handles buffering, playback, sample rate conversion, and channel mapping.

Comment: @Brad
How can I achieve this since node js doesn't support AudioContext?

Comment: It doesn't need to, and this wouldn't help you anyway.  Execute FFmpeg as a child process.  Pipe your audio data to it, get WebM data back out, pipe that to the client.

Comment: @Brad
Could you please share a reference that showcases how  FFmpeg works with audio?

Comment: @Brad
I was able to use this FFmpeg command:
 FFmpeg -f  s16le  -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i 'udp://192.168.1.230:65535' output.wav
to get the bytes from the UDP packet, and get an audio file out of it.
It's working very well, but I would like to know how to execute this command as a child process, pipe out to response in a format that the audio element can handel.

Comment: Try something like this:  `ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i 'udp://192.168.1.230:65535' -b:a 128k -f webm -`.  Use `child_process.spawn()` (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).  Take the resulting child process object's `stdout` stream and `.pipe()` to `res`.  (Make sure to set the `Content-Type: audio/webm` header first.)

Comment: @Brad
Well, I was able to execute the child-process and it's working. But, for some reason the browser is unable to play the audio, I have updated the question with a sample of code for more details.

Comment: What do your browser's developer tools say?  How are you loading the audio client-side? 
 You might need to specify a codec in the `Content-Type` response header as well.

Comment: @Brad 
Thanks a lot!!
I had to specify the codecs as you have mentioned.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to Brad, he directed me to the solution.

In node js server I had to do the following

- Execute the Ffmpe as a child process which receives the UDP packet as an input
- Pipe out each result of the child process into the response.

Here's the source code the node js server:

```
var http = require("http");
var port = 8888;
var host = "localhost";
var children = require("child_process");

http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    //ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i 'udp://192.168.1.230:65535' -b:a 128k -f webm -
    var ffm = children.spawn(
      "ffmpeg",
      "-f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i udp://192.168.1.230:65535 -b:a 128k -f webm -".split(
        " "
      )
    );

    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "audio/webm;codecs=vorbis" });
    ffm.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      res.write(data);
    });
  })
  .listen(port, host);

console.log("Server running at http://" + host + ":" + port + "/");
```

Client-side:

```
  <audio src="http://loclahost:8888" type='audio/webm; codecs="vorbis"' controls preload="none"></audio>
```