# How to play live audio in the browser from received UDP packets?

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I have node js server which receives BufferArrays over UDP, once a packet is received, socket.io do the next job which is emitting the BufferArray to the client (Angular).

Here's a sample code of the node js server implementation:

```
  io.on("connection", () => {
  server.on("listening", () => {
    let address = server.address();
    console.log("server host", address.address);
    console.log("server port", address.port);
  });

  server.on("message", function (message, remote) {
    arrayBuffer = message.slice(28);
    io.emit("audio", buffer); // // console.log(`Received packet: ${remote.address}:${remote.port}`)
  });
  server.bind(PORT, HOST);
});
```

In the client-side, I've created a blob object from the received BufferArray, then created an URL object to pass it to the audio element src.

```
 socket.on('audio', (audio) => {
      this.startAudio(audio);     
    });

      private startAudio(audio) {

    const blob = new Blob([audio], { type: "audio/wav" });

    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    // // console.log('blob', blob);
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // // console.log('url', url);
    audioElement.src = url;
    audioElement.play();
  }
```

But it seems, I'm doing it wrong since the audio isn't being played!!

So, I'm very curious to know the correct process of playing live audio streams in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to play live audio in the browser by using FFmpeg, here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231301/12954985) to the answer